# Azure data factory - data copying from adls to my DB in ascending order of date (not working)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to copy past 6 months data from ADLS to My Azure SQL DB using data factory pipeline.
When I entered start time and end time here in the source filter like below, it is copying data from current date and going back to old date (descending order) but my requirement is to copy data from old date to current date(ascending order). Please suggest how to get the data in ascending date order

[image: adls_source]

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to sort the source files in copy data activity.
You can store the file names with dates in a SQL table. And pull the list by sorting to process files in order.

1. Get the list of item names using the Get Metadata activity.
2. Pass the child items to ForEach activity.
3. Inside ForEach, get the last modified date of each item using the Get Metadata activity.
4. Pass the item name and Get Metadata output date to a Store procedure activity to insert data into a SQL table.
5. Add lookup activity to the ForEach activity, and get the files in order by date.
6. Pass the lookup activity output to another ForEach activity and copy that file data to sink.